# Is it a best practice to have a top level component in Angular2?

Tags: angular, dart

All is in the title :)

I want to create angular2 components in an already existing application.

In every tutorial I saw, there is a top level component which is created and contains all the features.

Is it really necessary to do so, or can I have multiple components not related with each other ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bootstrap more than one component.
The components need to have different selectors. 
You can use a shared services to communicate between these applications.

```
MyService myService = new MyService();

bootstrap(AppComponent1, [new Provider(MyService, useValue: myService)]);
bootstrap(AppComponent2, [new Provider(MyService, useValue: myService)]);
```

You should be aware that the change of one "app" that causes a callback to be called in another one, makes the callback run in the zone of the caller, not the receiver.
It was mentioned to get rid of NgZone in Angular2 Dart because it's not necessary there. I don't know yet if this will change anything.

Answer (score 0):

After RC5, we better to have modules which contain components.

> Every Angular app has at least one module class, the root module. We
>   bootstrap that module to launch the application.
>
> The root module is all we need in a simple application with a few
>   components. As the app grows, we refactor the root module into feature
>   modules that represent collections of related functionality. We then
>   import these modules into the root module.
>
> ## AppModule - the application root module
>
> Every Angular app has a root module class. By convention it's a class
>   called AppModule in a file named app.module.ts.

[official doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module)

You gotta have at least one component for the bootstrap. Then you can expand it or add routing (as require) later.

Comment: Angular2 for Dart doesn't and AFAIK won't get modules because they aren't necessary there.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am not aware of Dart.

Comment: I got that :D that's why I added the comment. The question has the [tag:dart] tag.